# Prove: If $x > 1$ and $y > 1$, then $xy >1$.

Tags: proof-writing

I am trying to prove that if $x > 1$ and $y > 1$, then $xy >1$.

I am thinking that we can use proof by contradiction.

So we can assume that $xy≤1$ and, $x>1$ and $y>1$.

I got stuck and don't know what should be the next statement.

Any comment and answer you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For such elementary proof, you have to be more precise about what is known. Otherwise I can just write : $x>1 \implies x \times y > 1\times y = y >1$.

Comment: Take $x=1+a,y=1+b$ . Then ?

Comment: @user710290 A very good approach. We have $a,b>0$ immediately giving the desired result.

Comment: @user710290, Thank you for your comment. 
Based on your suggestion, please let me know if this is correct.
Since $x>1$ and  $y>1$, then we can express $x=1+a$ and $y=1+b$ such that x and y are elements of the set of real numbers greater than 0. Hence, ...

Comment: To @user710290,

$xy=(1+a)(1+b)$
   $=1+x+y+xy$ 
Since $1+x+y+xy>1$, thus $xy>1$
QED.

Comment: @MAK Those should be $a$ and $b$ on right side of $=$

Comment: Noted. Thank you @user710290

Answer (score 2):

$$(y-1)(x-1)>0 \Rightarrow yx> x+y-1>x>1$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's take $x=t+1$ and $y=s+1$(here $t$ and $s$ are positive i.e >0)

we need to prove that $xy>1$

so $xy=(t+1)(s+1)$

$xy=st+s+t+1$

as we know $s$ and $t$ are positive then $s+t+st$ must be positive

Therefore,$xy>1$

Answer (score 0):

Because $$xy-1=xy-x+x-1=x(y-1)+(x-1)>0.$$